# Facebook Article Problem

Tags: facebook

Ok here is the think

suppose you want to submit a link to your mates wall,

You copy/paste a link and facebook generates title, image and description.

Curently i am working on http://www.compra.gr

When you want to submit this link (http://www.compra.gr) facebook generates characters that are not recognised.

When you want to submit http://compra.gr/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=35&Itemid=54

Facebook generates title,image and description normally.

I know that facebook takes the information from metadata. I corrected the metadata, however nothing happened.

Please help me if someone has a a clue what is going on.

Thank you in advance.

PS the site has copyright protection, in order to view the source code use google chrome and at the address bar enter view-source:http://compra.gr/

Comment: Both sites entered into Facebook return the same characters: COMPRA.GR: ΕΒΔΟΜΑΔΙΑΙΟ ΙΝΤΕΡΝΕΤΙΚΟ ΑΘΛΗΤΙΚΟ ΠΕΡΙΟΔΙΚΟ ΠΟΙΚΙΛΗΣ ΥΛΗΣ
Are these not the correct characters?

Comment: Yes this the correct one! Strange...5 min ago didnt work...All i changed is to remove lightbox js files. Hmmmmm

Comment: Pretty crappy "copyright protection"!

Answer (score 0):

I know whats the problem, your site does not have Open Graph tags!

Check out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Here's a snippet for you to understand, add this to your site and then use

URL Linter to Debug:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Open Graph Tags Snippet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="YOUR-POST-TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://YOUR-SITE-URL"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://YOUR-IMAGE-URL"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR-SITE-TITLE"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="YOUR-DESCRIPTION"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR-USER-ID"/>
</head>
.....
</html>
```